# Error trying to load data into Spyder

Tags: python, numpy, spyder

I'm having issues trying to pull data from a .txt file in a certain directory into Spyder. The basic idea is that I have a table of data in a .txt file, and I want certain columns to be used as arrays in Python. I'm using the numpy function genfromtxt() to do this, and it works fine when I write it as a program and then run it in Spyder. However, I'd like to interact with the array some more and since the file is very large, it takes a minute or so to load each time I want to make any small changes to the array. Eventually, I'm going to be working with even larger arrays so it would help to figure this out now. Currently, I'm using Spyder 2.3.5.2. If I try to use the console in order to load a .txt file, I'm getting the following error:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> allPlanetHosts = np.genfromtxt('planetHost.txt', comments='#', skip_header=5, usecols=(1,2,3,4))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1364, in genfromtxt
fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rbU'))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 151, in open
return ds.open(path, mode)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 501, in open
raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
IOError: planetHost.txt not found.
```

I have the directory set to the same one where planethost.txt file is located (in the bar in the top right, I changed the directory by pasting in the correct one), but is there something else I need to do in order to have it point to the correct directory? Thanks

Comment: That's odd. Is the output of this what you'd expect? `import os; os.getcwd()`

Comment: you should pass the full path to `'planetHost.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can't just paste the directory and hit enter...there's a button next to the text box that says "set as current directory." So even if you paste a directory in there and press enter, it won't actually set that as the directory until you hit that button. Thanks for the replies everyone